# Tenancy For Laravel package not syncing resources between tenants

Tags: laravel, multi-tenant, tenancyforlaravel

I am building a SAAS, where there is a super admin, which create branches (tenants), and those branches have resources (Customers, Documents....), I am using multi db to achieve tenancy (provided by the package).

When I create customer in Branch, its synced between the branch and the central db, e.g. I create customer in branch, the customer is created in central db as well and the entry is created in the pivot table (tenant_customers). Which proves I have setup the syncing correctly. But the customer is not synced to branch 2, that customer should be copied to all the other branches as well.

[Pivot Table Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZOEk.png)

Here is the Central Customer Model Code:

```
class Customer extends AbstractCustomer implements SyncMaster
{
    use CentralConnection, ResourceSyncing;

    public function tenants(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Branch::class, 'tenant_customers', 'global_id', 'tenant_id', 'global_id')
            ->using(TenantPivot::class);
    }
    
    public function getTenantModelName(): string
    {
        return TenantCustomer::class;
    }

    public function getGlobalIdentifierKey()
    {
        return $this->getAttribute($this->getGlobalIdentifierKeyName());
    }

    public function getGlobalIdentifierKeyName(): string
    {
        return 'global_id';
    }

    public function getCentralModelName(): string
    {
        return static::class;
    }

    public function getSyncedAttributeNames(): array
    {
        return $this->fillable;
    }
}
```

Here is the Tenant Customer Model:

```
class Customer extends AbstractCustomer implements Syncable
{
    use ResourceSyncing;

    public function getGlobalIdentifierKey()
    {
        return $this->getAttribute($this->getGlobalIdentifierKeyName());
    }

    public function getGlobalIdentifierKeyName(): string
    {
        return 'global_id';
    }

    public function getCentralModelName(): string
    {
        return CentralCustomer::class;
    }

    public function getSyncedAttributeNames(): array
    {
        return $this->fillable;
    }
}
```

Here is the store method code in Customer Controller:

```
public function store(StoreCustomerRequest $request)
    {
        $validatedData = $request->validated();

        $customer = new Customer($validatedData);
        $customer->save();

        return redirect()->route('tenant.customers.create', tenant('id'))
            ->with([
                'success', 'New Customer has been added!'
             ]);
    }
```

There is this code in the docs here https://tenancyforlaravel.com/docs/v3/synced-resources-between-tenants:

$user = CentralUser::create(...);

$user->tenants()->attach($tenant);

so this means for all the branches I have to attach manually, I tried it and get the following error:

Attempt to read property prepare on null.

Comment: It looks like you're using an example from the documentation that references a `customer`, but here you're working with a `user`. Make sure that the `$user` variable is properly instantiated and represents a valid `CentralUser` object. Also, ensure that `$tenant` is correctly assigned before calling the attach() method.